# rewrite a folder name using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am wondering wether it's possible to use `.htaccess` to rewrite a folder name. 
What I mean is this.

Lets say I have a url like:

```
www.site.com/folder1/page.php
```

Now I want to rewrite the url to (for example)

```
www.site.com/apple/page.php
```

The folder1 is an existing folder on my webspace.

**important: the "apple" is not a folder rather just a name!**

Ok here is a step by step plan:

1. User types `www.site.com/folder1/login.php`
2. The url should rewrite and not redirect the url to `www.site.com/apple/login.php`

This means that `apple` is just a name and not a directory. All the code should just come from folder1. Acutally apple should just be an alias for `folder1`. I can't just rename `folder1` to `Apple`. Therefor I would just rewrite `folder1` to `apple`.

Comment: does the apple folder exist on your webspace too?

Comment: sorry you need to be clearer what you want to happen. can you give us a step by step what you want to happen eg what the url that the user types in and where the actual file is in your webspace.

Comment: I updated I hope its more clear.

Comment: In the first part, it seams that the "folder1" is hidden to the user which should see "apple" instead. But you "clarified" by adding "user types www.site.com/folder1/login.php"... Can you clarify... again...?

Comment: when the user types  www.site.com/folder1/login.php it should change the url to www.site.com/apple/login.php where apple is just an alias for folder1.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

mod_rewrite can only rewrite/redirect requested URIs. So you would need to request `/apple/…` to get it rewritten to a corresponding `/folder1/…`.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^apple/(.*) folder1/$1
```

This rule will rewrite every request that starts with the URI path `/apple/…` internally to `/folder1/…`.

---

**Edit**    As you are actually looking for the other way round:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /folder1/
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) /apple/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule is designed to work together with the other rule above. Requests of `/folder1/…` will be redirected externally to `/apple/…` and requests of `/apple/…` will then be rewritten internally back to `/folder1/…`.

Comment: Ah, Gumbo I think you're right.  I misunderstood what the original poster meant, it's described backwards.  +1

Comment: I tried this with  http://site.com/folder1/login.php but it doesnt rewrite to http://site.com/apple/login.php

Comment: @sanders: As I already said, you have to request `/apple/login.php` to have it rewritten to `/folder1/login.php`.

Comment: @Gumbo: I want  to rewrite folder1/login.php to apple/login.php and tried therefore RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) apple/$1 but doesn't work. 
I even tried it with the indows regex tester but the patterns don't mactch

Comment: With your edit it shows now www.site.com/apple/login.php but on the screen i see an error since it says that it can't find the requested page.

Comment: @sanders: Did you use both rules together?

Comment: Yes now I use both rules together
It doesn't work yet 100%

because when I am on http://site.com/apple/login.php
and go to http://site.com/apple/index.php it sends me back to 
http://site.com/Folder1/index.php

Comment: @Gumbo could you please look at my problem also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618308/url-rewriting-redirecting-restricting-on-multiple-conditions-using-htaccess/42618367?noredirect=1#comment72366189_42618367

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
RewriteRule ^/apple(.*)?$ /folder1$1 [NC]
```

Where the folder you want to appear in the url is in the first part of the statement - this is what it will match against and the second part 'rewrites' it to your existing folder. the [NC] flag means that it will ignore case differences eg Apple/ will still forward.

See here for a tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/

There is also a nice test utility for windows you can download from here:
http://www.helicontech.com/download/rxtest.zip
**Just to note for the tester you need to leave out the domain name - so the test would be against /folder1/login.php**

to redirect from /folder1 to /apple try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder1(.*)?$ /apple$1 [R]
```

to redirect and then rewrite just combine the above in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder1(.*)?$ /apple$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/apple(.*)?$ /folder1$1 [NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your help but when i test it on this:
I tried this with site.com/folder1/login.php but it doesnt rewrite to site.com/apple/login.php 
I get patterns not mach

Comment: @Josh: your edit RewriteRule ^/folder1(.*)?$ /apple1$1 [R] doesn't work eiter.

Comment: Are this redirects slower? when the redirect happens, comparing to a non redirect version?

Comment: unfortunately the test utility download link above no longer works