# .htaccess set my url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I am looking for `.htaccess` documentation/tutorial but not getting it properly, I don't know it is not my level to learn now or something else.
please also recommend links to learn .htaccess

but here I have to set my urls
on server my main website is on root directory
beside that i have my other sites in a subdirectory `/sites` as

```
/sites/myblog
/sites/myfriends
/sites/other
```

currently these are being accessed `www.domain.com/sites/myblog`
but I want to set its url as `www.domain.com/myblog` replacing `sites`
I am using apache

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# it is not already /sites/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ sites%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Also some good documentation on `mod_rewrite`:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)
- [Apache mod_rewrite beginner's Tutorial](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)