# Wordpress wp-admin directory change using htaccess

Tags: wordpress

How to change wordpress wp-admin directory for wordpress (version) 4.2.2 using htaccess.

Now: http://www.example.com/wp-admin
but i want to make this type of url

http://www.example.com/example

It must be needed by htaccess.
is it possible?

Comment: There is a plugin, that make this with url rewrite. [Hide My WP](http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158), but it's not free.

Comment: I use for this [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) It will redirect wp-admin to login page

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rename the wp-admin directory ?

Edit:
Renaming is not good idea

Answer:
use this htaccess rule in your .htaccess file

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*) example/$1`

Comment: Renaming the directory is a bad idea.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess

Comment: I will rephrase my comment "Renaming the WordPress admin directory is a bad idea"