# .htaccess file not able to rename subfolder instead getting page not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have search alot on google and even on stackoverflow.com too. I have found some good questions and their answer but unfortunately no answer working for me. I have written a cms kind web application in which public access files are on root where control panel files resides on admin folder. Now i want all control panel files should run using http://www.example.com/administrator url, for this i have written this .httacess file.

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN     
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^single _single_Page.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^single/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _single_Page.php?subid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^findcontents$ _findContentTitle.php [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^findcontents/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _findContentTitle.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search$ _specificPage.php [NC,L] [L,QSA]




# Admin panel redirect settings

RewriteRule ^/administrator(.*)?$ /admin$1 [NC]


RewriteRule ^authenticate _checkaccess.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>

# END
```

From root file working fine, but when i tried www.example.com/administrator. I am getting page not found error. Please somebody help me. what i have mistaken in the .htaccess file.

i have been refer for rename folder using [rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)

I have also tried this code too

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ /admin/%1 [L]
```

but still i am getting page not found error. just for the knowledge i am using godaddy hosting. above example working fine for localhost. but not working on godaddy hosting.

Comment: The two admin rules don't really do anything at the moment. The first will rewrite to the second which will rewrite back to the first. What actual *page* are you trying to get when using `example.com/administrator`?

Comment: i have tried second one but it is not working. Ok i will remove first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^administrator(.*)$ /admin$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^authenticate _checkaccess.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^single _single_Page.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^single/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _single_Page.php?subid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^findcontents$ _findContentTitle.php [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^findcontents/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _findContentTitle.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search$ _specificPage.php [NC,L] [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Please tell me what i have mistaken in the .htaccess file.it seam similar to mine but working correctly.

Comment: You had a leading slash in your RewriteRule and order of rules was not correct.

Comment: Ok, it means order metter right. Thanks budy for your valuable help and support.