# how to change the url address in a link ( <a> tag)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting

I have a web directory localhost/web/folder1/folder2/
When I make a link `<a href="login.php">` in the folder2, then the result is localhost/web/folder1/folder2/login.php

How rewrite display name of folder2 localhost/web/folder1/folder2/login.php to localhost/web/folder1/new_folder2/login.php without canged `<a href="login.php">` ?

Comment: You have to specify more details in your question. Currently it simply is too vague. It is unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but have you tried using something like `<a href="../new_folder2/login.php">`? You might not need to touch .htaccess at all, but just use `../` to go one level up on the relative directory path.

If you specifically want .htaccess to take care of that take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess) on how to rewrite a folder name.