# Is it possible to re-direct a URL when other site's code is in root directory

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have a web site I'm re-building that has it's code in the root of the domain; I also have the existing (original) website in the same domain in the folder QnE.

Is there a way that when the user enters xyz.com that I can somehow point it to xyz.com/qne (original code), leaving the new code in the root of the domain?  I understand what I'm asking (that both should be in separate directories for this to work) but I thought I'd ask anyway *just in case there is a way to do it.*

Comment: If you're on apache you could use .htaccess to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess

Comment: That's what I thought... please re-write your comment as the answer... thank you for responding.

Comment: Thank you @spokane-dude for keeping stackoverflow clean. Also for the accept/upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on apache you could use .htaccess, take a look at this post on [how to rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)