# Any ideas for alternative ways of rewriting URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url, hyperlink, url-rewriting

At the moment, I use a community open source software. And its everything fine.
My question is not a big deal, it's not a bug to crash or stop my website. It's not scary. 
Just I want to know more, because I tried too much different ways (for the problem I'll talk below), but obviously I'm just not good enough troubleshooter.
So... Let me finally explain what it is about. 
I have URL like that:

> https://someexamplewebsitehere.com/forum

And I want to make it like that:

> https://someexamplewebsitehere.com/forov

(where "forov" is the same as "forum" in my native language)

I want the content of the page to be exactly the same (mirror). Not different installation. Just I want to rewrite it. I want to be some kind of alias, but I have not permissions over the webserver, I just have cPanel and that's all.

Similar solution is explained here 
[rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)
but obviously, it does not work for my website.

The default CMS .htaccess file looks like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/e500\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/captcha\.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

And I do not want to make custom modifications in the forum plugin, because I'll lose these modifications in case of plugin update. If it's possible, I want to just rewrite the URL.

I tried so many variants.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's funny how some people downvote the question, but at the same time they do not leave a constructive comment with a solution for the problem to show for the student "how to do it". ;) Yes, there are many examples for such a problems even in Stack overflow, but they are not every time working! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this.

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forov/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This is how I use it for my CMS clients.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forov/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Also use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
```

If all else fail and if it is just that page, you could make a fake page and use a 301 redirect, which basically says this page is the same page but is here now. It is the correct way to use redirects for actual pages that are elsewhere and you do not want to lose page rank and to inform searchbots.

ie yoursite.com/forum

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.YourWebsite.com/forov"); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank You very much @norcal johnny for your answer! I tried that yesterday, but for some reasons it doesnt work in that cms.

Comment: @saly_bat, updated the answer to the full code I use.

Comment: I appreciate you answer! Really! You are helpful for me and other people like me. I also figured the option using a fake page, but there is a problem with initializing the forum plugin (there are different problems in that case, like example a duplication of the navigation menu that complicates the problem, anyway).

Comment: Did you try adding the other codes in between the original post and the 301 redirect...

Comment: I tried like that: 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forov/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://examplewebste.com/forov' , but in that case it's not rewriting, its similar to the fake page case

Comment: It's some issue, because the specific cms, I think. Because I have other websites, where your solution is 1000% working!

Comment: I meant like so.. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forov/$1 [R=301,NC,L] and also add Options -Indexes under Options +FollowSymlinks.

Comment: Yes, @norcal johnny, I tried like that. No success.