# htaccess 301 redirect wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for a 301 wildcard redirect solution for the following.
I changed the following url layout.

https://www.example.com/print-scan

to

https://www.example.com/printing

Now all old pages should be redirecting to the new URL layout, so for example:

https://www.example.com/print-scan/scanners/product1

must go to

https://www.example.com/printing/scanners/product1

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^print-scan(/.*)?$ /printing$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Pattern `(/.*)?` allows you match any of the following URIs:

- `/print-scan` (no trailing slash)
- `/print-scan/` (with trailing slash)
- `/print-scan/anything`
- `/print-scan/scanners/product1`