# How to deploy a Gatsby site to a Wordpress sub-directory?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, gatsby

I have a 'portfolio' subdirectory of a Wordpress site, so the the site structure looks something like this...

```
www.sitename.com/portfolio/project-1
www.sitename.com/portfolio/project-2
www.sitename.com/portfolio/project-3
```

...and for the page at 'project-3' I've built a page with Gatsby and would like to host it there. The other projects would stay as Wordpress pages, but just the 'project-3' page would be built with Gatsby. How does one go about doing this? I imagine it involves 'pathPrefix' in 'gatsby-config.js', but once I have my page built how do I drop it into my Wordpress site. This Medium article shows how to do it with vanilla React... https://medium.com/@ReactionGears/react-app-inside-a-wordpress-page-or-post-4c7d38181b3d
...but I'm not sure how it translates to Gatsby. Any help with this would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: It should probably be sufficient to set the [`pathPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/) to `/portfolio` and upload the built Gatsby site into your `portfolio/` directory.

Comment: @FabianSchultz right, but I forgot to mention, the portfolio page is built using a page template, and each project page is built using a template. So there's no directory called 'portfolio' to drop the files into on the FTP, if that makes sense? :)

Comment: Ah I see, in that case maybe try modifying the `.htaccess` to rewrite that path to the location where you host the Gatsby site. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess) are some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @fabian-schultz is correct, you can build the Gatsby site with a [`pathPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/) and then put that site into a subdirectory.

WordPress uses "virtual" subdirectories so `/portfolio` will not exist on your filesystem. You can either change the portfolio directories to be `/portfolio-project-1` (so a single folder instead of a nested folder), or you can create the `/portfolio` directory. If you do that, you need to copy the `index.php` file from the `/` directory and then change the include path.

Your `portfolio/index.php` file might look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wp-blog-header.php' );
```

The `/..` on the last line tells WordPress to search in the folder above for the `wp-blog-header.php` file.