# Shortern URL with .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, angularjs

I have deployed wordpress blog with php on a single domain. I want to rewrite the rule in root .htaccess file like below.

Current URL :- http://www.abcd.com/blog/ (Which is running now)
Expected URL :- http://www.abcd.com/myblog/

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace the Folder Name "blog" to "myblog"

Comment: But I want do the rewrite rule using .htaccess or server configuration

Comment: Its already solved here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess"

Just look at it once