# How Can I Change LearnDash Permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, url-rewriting, permalinks

I installed the "Learndash" plugin in WordPress.
Shared Course Steps is enabled in Course Settings and nested URLs is enabled.

This is my question.
how can i change this url :
https://yoursite.com/courses/course-name/lessons/lesson-name/topic/topic-name/
to this url :
https://yoursite.com/courses/course-name/lesson-name/topic-name/

I took a look at this link:
https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/core/settings/permalinks/#custom_rewrite_rules

but i can't use generate_rewrite_rules.
do you know how to use it?

Please tell me the solution.
thank you :)

Comment: Are you searching for solution with .htaccess ?

Comment: Any solution that makes it work is good for me. can you tell me the solution with .htaccess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rewrite a folder name using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264773/rewrite-a-folder-name-using-htaccess)

Comment: look at this : https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/core/settings/permalinks/#shortening_nested_urls

Comment: i can't use generate_rewrite_rules. can you?

Comment: With the link you sent, it is written the doc for custom url path: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules adn said that you should use: generate_rewrite_rules

Comment: Where should I add the code 'generate_rewrite_rules' in WordPress?

Comment: Here an example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82005/how-to-specify-urls-for-custom-posts-taxonomies . I would suggest you post your question on  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which same family of stackoverflow but specialized for wordpress

Comment: thank you so much :)